# Nginx to serve multiple files in one request

Tags: nginx

I have 10 files, log1.txt, log2.txt, log3.txt

I would like to have an nginx endpoint, /log that will return all 3 logs to the client.

So if log1.txt was

```
BASEBALL
```

log2.txt was

```
BASKETBALL
```

log3.txt was

```
SWIMMING
```

/log would return

```
BASEBALL
BASKETBALL
SWIMMING
```

(though order in my use case wouldn't matter)

What's important is that the nginx server not load all of the files in memory (to concat, tar or whatever), since these files may be huge and eat up all the available memory. I would like nginx to stream the files to the client.

Is this possible with nginx?

Answer (score 4):

First, I should say that this task looks rather odd to me, which might indicate that your question is an "[XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)". Perhaps, if you would describe your original problem, we could find a better solution to it.

Now back to your question. Surprisingly, Nginx does provide some means to achieve this goal, although they are not exactly obvious. The easiest option, in my opinion, would be to use the SSI module, which comes with almost every distribution of Nginx.

The configuration in this case would look somewhat like this:

```
server {

    ...

    location /log {
        # Parse the contents of the response body 
        # as if it were an SSI template
        ssi on;
        # And parse it whatever the Content-Type (MIME)
        # of the response body is
        ssi_types *;

        # Make an internal redirect to the internal
        # location in order to get an SSI template
        rewrite ^/log$ /log/template;

        location /log/template {
            # Make sure this location is not available
            # from the outside world
            internal;

            # You can set any mime type here
            default_type text/plain;

            # Combine files any way you like using
            # the SSI template language
            return 200 '<!--# include file="/log/log1.txt" -->
                        <!--# include file="/log/log2.txt" -->
                        <!--# include file="/log/log3.txt" -->';
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

You can find the description and examples of SSI commands in the official [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html).

In order to achieve a better performance, it could also be a good idea to employ [sendfile](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#sendfile) together with [aio](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#aio) and [tcp_nopush](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#tcp_nopush). This can be done by setting these directives together with [ssi_min_file_chunk](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html#ssi_min_file_chunk). [Here](https://t37.net/nginx-optimization-understanding-sendfile-tcp_nodelay-and-tcp_nopush.html) you can read about sendfile and what it is used for.

However, even without these settings Nginx will work fast and will not eat up your memory.